# How do I call the self.timer's changing value and indicate it at the label.text the ViewDidLoad's

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm making a UILabel that indicates the value of the self.timer.

This is the code.
The problem is that I can't indicate the timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date_SSS) in the label.text.

Actually I also have a scrollView and a pageControl to scroll the label horizontally. But the main problem is at the UILabel and the self.timer.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var label: UILabel!
    private var timer: NSTimer!
    let intArray: String = ["12:00:00", "12:50:00", "15:30:00", "16:40:00"]
    let i = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.timer.fire()

        for (var i = 0; i < intArray.count; i++) {
            let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(index) * 50,100,150,200)
            label.cornerRadius = 20
            label.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date_SSS)
            view.addSubView(label)
        }

    }

    func dateFromString(date:String) -> NSDate? {
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        calendar.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "JST")!
        let begin = date.startIndex
        guard let hour = Int(date.substringWithRange(begin..<begin.advancedBy(2))),
            let minute = Int(date.substringWithRange(begin.advancedBy(3)..<begin.advancedBy(5))),
            let second = Int(date.substringWithRange(begin.advancedBy(6)..<begin.advancedBy(8))) else{
                return nil
        }

        return calendar.dateBySettingHour(hour, minute: minute, second: second, ofDate: NSDate(), options: [])

    }

    func update(timer: NSTimer)  {

        let timeFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

        let time = dateFromString(intArray[i])
        let remain = time!.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate())
        let date_SSS = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: remain)

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this even build? I can see a lot of errors. For example `let intArray: String = ["12:00:00", "12:50:00", "15:30:00", "16:40:00"]` won't work since you are trying to make an array of type `String` rather than `[String]`.  In `viewDidLoad()` when you declare `label` you're missing a final bracket. I'm also pretty sure that UILabels don't have a `cornerRadius` property.

Answer (score 0):

well, you are not setting your label in your update method, so it's hard to see how it would change. maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. And the point you are approaching is not wrong. i tried setting the label in the update() function but a problem occurs if i set like that. the Label will also made by 1 sec as it is said in the self.timer and it's appearance is very dirty. How can i solve it?